# php exec() doesn't store the output in $output argument

Tags: php, r

My `index.php`:

```
<?php
    $n = 3;
    exec("Rscript my_script.R $n", $out);
    var_dump($out);
<?
```

`my_script.R`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

i <- as.numeric(commandArgs(TRUE))
rootkea <- mongoDbConnect('rootkea')
print(i:10)
```

Output:

```
array(0) { }
```

Shell Output:

```
$ Rscript my_script.R 3
Loading required package: rJava
Loading required package: methods
[1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

---

Interestingly the php works as expected if I remove `mongoDbConnect` line from `my_script.R`
Modified `my_script.R`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

i <- as.numeric(commandArgs(TRUE))
#rootkea <- mongoDbConnect('rootkea')
print(i:10)
```

Output:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(27) "[1] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10" }
```

Shell Output:

```
$ Rscript my_script.R 3
Loading required package: rJava
Loading required package: methods
[1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

I need to have the database connection and other processing in `my_script.R` *before* I print the result. How do I make `exec` store the output in `$out` argument?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok.

Try this ugly hack:

```
$temp = tempnam(null, null);
$temp2 = tempnam(null, null);
exec("Rscript my_script.R $n > \"$temp\" 2> \"$temp2\"");
$out = file_get_contents($temp);
$err = file_get_contents($temp2);
unlink($temp);
unlink($temp2);
```

Comment: Now the output I got is: `string(0) ""`

Comment: Another interesting bit if I add `print(i:5)` *before* `mongoDbConnect` keeping previous `print` intact, I get output as : `string(10) "[1] 3 4 5 " `. It's as if `mongoDbConnect` is failing. But I can verify that it is not by running from the shell.

Comment: Are you running the PHP code in the command line or in the web server? If it's in the web server -Apache, Nginx or whatever- check which user is calling the script and make sure that user has permissions to run it and read/write to the needed folders or files. On Apache the user is most probably `www-data`.

Comment: Since I'm testing right now I have the most insecure permissions 777. Besides, documentation says "If the directory does not exist or is not writable, tempnam(3) may generate a file in the  system´s  temporary  directory, and return the full path to that file, including its name." So I don't think it's a permission issue.

Comment: I modified the code to see if the script outputs something to the standard error --saved in the variable `$err`.